# How to update an ISO installed with Rufus?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-storage, rufus

I've installed an Ubuntu 17.04 ISO on my external hard drive with Rufus to make it bootable.

After that, I've saved some data (pictures for example) on my drive as well.

Now, can I override that Ubuntu 17.04 ISO with another one (in my case, 18.04 Ubuntu) without losing my pictures?

Please note that I don't have anywhere else to store my data: it far exceeds the total space I have on my PC and don't have another drive to copy temporarily onto, and with my internet connection it would take weeks to save it on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is precarious: if you have no backup image of the external HDD, you might lose *all* your data for any number of reasons.

- A HDD, like any mechanical device, has a finite lifetime and eventually wears out.
- Malware or other cause could damage the file system.
- User errors can delete files or format a partition. This update falls into that category.
- The HDD could be lost to accident or theft.

Since you're storing data on the drive, I assume you've partitioned it and made a persistent storage area. [An ISO image **cannot** be updated easily.](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) *After* you back up the drive, you might be best served by actually *installing* Ubuntu 18.04 on the HDD, which would allow security and other updates to be made directly from the web by the OS. The easiest way to do so would be booting from a flash USB drive with Ubuntu 18.04 and install it in a new partition of the HDD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
While installing Ubuntu on the HDD is, technically, probably the best idea, it doesn't answer both my needs.
I really need a solution that achieves two things: the ability to install itself on a computer if needed, and the ability to boot on the HDD and reset the OS every time I launch it.